# how to reset a form textarea after submiting with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem on how to reset my Textarea to be empty and also show the placeholder once user submit the form using ajax, right now am able to successfully submit the form and empty the Textarea but after that if the user click submit again it will submit an empty form and bypass my form validation due to the form did not reset rather it just end up emptying the Textarea only, please someone should help out I don't know the best way to explain this I hope someone understand a give a solution

```
$("body").on("keydown",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
         if ($(".img_comment").is(":focus") && $(".img_comment").val() != "") {
             $(".img_comment_f").ajaxForm({
                 success: function(response){
                     //alert(response);
                     $(".img_comment").val(" ");
                 },
                 error: function(){
                    alert("check error");
                 }
            }).trigger("submit");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the value of the textarea with a space (therefore it's not empty). Try the following:

```
$("body").on("keydown",function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    if ($(".img_comment").is(":focus") && $(".img_comment").val() != "") {

       $(".img_comment_f").ajaxForm({
            success: function(response){
              //alert(response);
              $(".img_comment").val("");
            },
            error: function(){
              alert("check error");
            }
       }).trigger("submit");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.area51').val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="area51" placeholder="i am a placeholder">this is some text</textarea>
```

Snippet provided.
This is the way to empty the textarea. FYI.

Comment: what i want is when i empty the textarea then the placeholder in will be visible again but the one you show will just empty but the placeholder will not show and if user click submit it will bypass your form validation